# Splitting a column into 2 for csv, fails if one name

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I need to export contacts from multiple people, and modify the tab deliminted file to a csv in a specific way. The exported file only has two columns, Name and Email, but I need it to be Email, Name, FirstName, LastName. My script, while probably crude and I set it up to run as a sendto, does work. I'm running into an issue though if someone doesn't have a second name listed. Can I put an if statement around the split? It keeps breaking when I try.

Here is some sample date like what I start with. It starts with two columns, a few lines I need to skip, and then a list of name/emails. It does come in tab del. but thats difficult to show here.

Group Name    groupxyz

Members

Bill Ted, bted@domain.c,

Rick Seb, rseb@domain.c,

Susie, susie@mail.c,

tom cruze, tom@link.o,

Here is my code so far.

```
  "Received $($args.Count) files:"
foreach( $path in $args ) {
"Processing file: $path"   
$filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($path)
}
Import-CSV -Path $path  -Delimiter "," -Header Email, Name, FirstName, LastName | select -skip 4 |
ForEach-Object{
$first, $last = $_.Email -split " "
$_.FirstName = "$first"
$_.LastName = "$last"
$email = $_.Name
$_.Name = "$first $last"
$_.Email = $email
$_
} |
 Export-CSV C:\Users\jjasper\Desktop\Composer\ContactExport\result\$filename -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
(Get-Content -Path C:\import\$filename ).Replace('"','') | Set-Content -Path C:\import\$filename
(Get-Content -Path C:\import\$filename ) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content C:\import\$filename
```

Comment: Paste sample rows of the raw CSV data in code block so we can recreate the condition and write a sample of the desired output. Using pipeline like this will not make it easy for you to see where your code fails and it is very hard to track, try break it in to different sections instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to help you out without having some sample of the csv content. However, I think you should try to work with objects to manipulate the data the way you want, for example, if your CSV has 4 headers here is what you can do with it.

```
$csvImport = Import-CSV -Path $path -Header Email, Name, FirstName, LastName

$reOrderExport=@()

foreach($row in $csvImport){

    $obj=[PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $row.FirstName + $row.LastName
        email = $row.Email
        userName = ($row.Email -split '@')[0]
        familiyName = if($row.LastName -like ''){
            'noLastName'
        }else{
            $row.LastName
        }
    }

    $reOrderExport+=$obj
    
}

$reOrderExport | Export-CSV -Path $exportPath -NoTypeInformation
```

You simply get all the CSV content and work through the imported data to generate the array you want, and then export that or keep adding it to a file if you go through list of csv's.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll see what I can do with. Just in case you do come back, I did add some data. There aren't extra lines in the txt file I get, except before and after Members.